# GVR SDK ( Google VR Player) ios start video on button click

Tags: ios, swift, button, video

I'm trying to play a video on clic of a button ( it should start the video in fullscreen) Using GVR SDK for IOs in Swift.

I've been following this tutorial to make the player working in swift;

https://www.raywenderlich.com/136692/introduction-google-cardboard-ios

but it idpslay the video on the view controller.

Current on my view controller I have a button, on press, it should start to play the video in full screen.

For this I tried to create the following action:

```
 @IBAction func videoButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
            var url = URL(string: "https://myvideo.mp4")
            var videoController = GVRVideoView(nibName: "GVRVideoView", bundle: nil, url: url)
            videoController.vrMode(true)
            if !self.presentedView.isBeingDismissed() {
                self.present(videoController, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
            }
        }
```

but no success ....does anybody have any idea how can this be achieve ???

or i'f I'm in a good track ??

Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `displayMode` of `GVRVideoView` TO `kGVRWidgetDisplayModeFullscreenVR` OR `kGVRWidgetDisplayModeFullscreen`

here is code i use to display video in full screen

```
videoView.enableFullscreenButton = YES;
videoView.enableCardboardButton = YES;
videoView.displayMode = kGVRWidgetDisplayModeFullscreenVR;
[videoView play];
```